# Como pegar informações de hardware e do sistema?

Tags: java

Encontrei só a classe `Runtime`, mas ela retorna somente valores em números, como o total de memória e processadores. Existe alguma API que retorne os dados de *hardware* (versão de processador, memória RAM, arquitetura, etc.) como no CCleaner?

Comment: Acho que te pode ajudar https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home Exemplo de como usar http://stackoverflow.com/q/12214114/3792998

Answer (score 4):

Eu utilizo o [SIGAR](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsigarjar.htm) basicamente faz isso que voce pediu:  [Documentacao](http://sigar.hyperic.com)

Depois de fazer o download do SAGAR API.Jar e de o incluir no path de compilação, segue-se um exemplo de utilização:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;

import org.hyperic.sigar.Mem;
import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException;

public class MemExample {
    private static Sigar sigar = new Sigar();

    public static void getInformationsAboutMemory() {
        System.out.println("**************************************");
        System.out.println("*** Informations about the Memory: ***");
        System.out.println("**************************************\n");

        Mem mem = null;
        try {
            mem = sigar.getMem();
        } catch (SigarException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Actual total free system memory: " + mem.getActualFree() / 1024 / 1024 + " MB");
        System.out.println("Actual total used system memory: " + mem.getActualUsed() / 1024 / 1024 + " MB");
        System.out.println("Total free system memory ......: " + mem.getFree() / 1024 / 1024 + " MB");
        System.out.println("System Random Access Memory....: " + mem.getRam() + " MB");
        System.out.println("Total system memory............: " + mem.getTotal() / 1024 / 1024 + " MB");
        System.out.println("Total used system memory.......: " + mem.getUsed() / 1024 / 1024 + " MB");

        System.out.println("\n**************************************\n");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        getInformationsAboutMemory();
    }

}
```